# Exposing POCOs as web service using IOC - alternatives for Spring.net's WebServiceExporter?

Tags: .net, web-services, castle-windsor, spring.net

Previously using [spring.net's](http://springframework.net) excellent support for [web services](http://springframework.net/doc-latest/reference/html/webservices.html), I really enjoyed the ability to use IOC with existing web services. Allowing them to change seamlessly through different Dev, Test AND Prod environments.

This was fine as we used spring.net's IOC and Validation frameworks as well.

Now, we use Castle Windsor and no longer need spring.net as much.

What alternative can we use to get the same web service functionality that we got from spring.net, namely Exposing POCOs as Web Services and being able to use IOC with a web service?

Comment: Castle Windsor can create dynamic proxies too...

Comment: @Mark - OP is looking for an alternative to spring's ["export webservice from poco" functionality](http://www.springframework.net/doc-latest/reference/html/webservices.html#web-services-introduction); I guess the title is a bit misleading here.

Comment: @shenku - please consider updating your title; see mark's remark

Comment: @shenku - I updated the title and tags; if you don't think it's an improvement, please roll back.

Answer (score 1):

Windsor has the [WCF Integration Facility](http://docs.castleproject.org/Windsor.WCF-Integration-Facility.ashx) that serves a similar purpose.